# the JSON works but print an error in console

Tags: javascript, json

I want to show Json data when the href text is clicked.it works but whenever I clicked the href text the console prints "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in file data.json. why this is happening? I have validate the code in JSONLint.

file:index. html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Using jQuery to retrieve Json via Ajax</h1>
    <a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON data</a>
</body>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#clickme").click(function(){
            $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
                var items=[];;
                $.each(data,function(key,val){
                    items.push('<li id="'+key+'">'+val+'</li>');
                });
                console.log(items);

                $("<ul/>",{
                    "class":"interest-list",
                    html:items.join("")
                }).appendTo("body");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

file:data.json

```
{
    "one":"pikachu is awesome",
    "two":"squirtle is awesome"
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Is it the whole error message, or did you cut it ?

Comment: please print full error message from console, may be there is some line number which will help.
also, check if your data.json file has last line empty while saving it ? if yes, please remove and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your data.json file:

you must change your json like this (using [ ] ):

```
[
    {
      "one":"pikachu is awesome",
      "two":"squirtle is awesome"
    }
]
```

then you must change your js code to use data[0] instead of data:

```
$.each(data[0],function(key,val){
    items.push('<li id="'+key+'">'+val+'</li>');
});
```

this prevent the console error and all works fine.

p.s.: i suggest to remove the unnedded ; in line 14:

```
var items=[];;
```

to

```
var items=[];
```